# Create an advanced filter: two urls for the same website

Tags: google-analytics

I am following this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185657/track-goals-across-subdomains-in-google-analytics/44185949#44185949) to create an advanced filter in order to capture visits to a website looks like: http://sub.example1.com.

Please note that we also have another URL for this website: http://sub.example2.com for historical reasons.

When creating the advanced filter, should I just enter `sub.example1.com` for hostname?

Or should I create another advanced filter for this view to enter `sub.example2.com` for hostname?

Comment: are you using the same GA Account? Why do you want to create a filter? What's the purpose?

Comment: They are using the same GA account. I am creating it according to your advice to my earlier post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205845/is-my-code-for-correct-for-having-two-accounts-for-the-same-website

Comment: But you don't have to mention any hostname for that filter. You need to place regex like (.*) i.e. every host name. It will append automatically, you just need to follow the steps here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185657/track-goals-across-subdomains-in-google-analytics/44185949#44185949

Comment: If I use (.*) for the hostname, how can this filter to capture visits for this site? Please note that I have another website under the same account. Thanks!

Comment: uhm oki this filter is not filtering any thing, its just making your page dimension complete. any hit send to this UA id will be recorded. So if you look into page dimension you have the values like /home.html or /index.html. but you cant see which host /domain it was on. this filter will help you to add the domain in your page dimension. so after this filter, the values will be like sub.example1.com/home.html or sub.example2.com/index.html. You just need to send the data from both website to same property id(UAid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're trying to filter on a hostname to include, so you only capture traffic coming from these 2 hostnames?

This can be done with an advanced/custom filter with a regular expression:

```
^sub\.example1\.com$|^sub\.example2\.com$
```

Comment: No problem @curious1 , if this solved your problem please accept the answer for others having this problem.

Comment: Hi Jelman, Tushar helped me with another question. I created this post based on his advice for creating an advanced filter, and I followed his/her suggestion for the hostname of the filter. One question: In the advanced/custom filter, I can enter regular expression for the hostname?

Comment: If you choose custom you can indeed.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! I am gong to use your input to create another view with the filter as you suggested.

Comment: No problem, we use this way of working on our company websites because we have 2 domains in dutch & french (belgium) just make sure you use the same GA-id offcourse and this way it will only accept data coming from both Hostnames

Comment: uhm that is not the recommended way for advanced filters. you cant use the vaue of A and B variable if you use it this way. Read google post here https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034836?hl=en&ref_topic=1034830 @Jelman